# Extracting and managing array elements in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

The main objective of this code is the ability for a user to highlight/favourite a page in application. I have an array of quotes which is scrolled through by the user on button click. **I would like to have it so that when a "favourite" button is clicked (not implemented in code yet).  The current element which the user is viewing is extracted (The whole string?) and then somehow marked / sent into another array.** This array is then displayed using my own method. I don't know how this could be done. Here's my viewcontroller file.

```
import UIKit

class DreamViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var QuoteImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var DreamLabel: UILabel!
    var counter = 1

    var factIndex = 0

    let dreamFact = Dream()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        DreamLabel.text = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func LeftSwipe() {
        factIndex--
        var number = dreamFact.dreamArray.count - 1
        if (factIndex < 0){
            self.factIndex = number

        }
        DreamLabel.text = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]
        if counter == 1 {

            counter = 36

        } else {

            self.counter--

        }

        QuoteImage.image = UIImage(named: "frame\(counter).jpg")

    }





    @IBAction func RightSwipe() {
        factIndex++
        if factIndex >= dreamFact.dreamArray.count {
            self.factIndex = 0
        }
        DreamLabel.text = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]



    if counter == 36 {

    counter = 1

    } else {

    self.counter++

    }

    QuoteImage.image = UIImage(named: "frame\(counter).jpg")

}
}
```

if any additional information is required please let me now as soon as possible. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the factIndex, that you're using to track the current index, to remove the particular "quote" from the dreamArray that the user has favourited. Seeing as the factIndex is correct in tracking the current quote the user is viewing we know that we can use this  to extract the right object from the array.

The suggestion below presumes that you create an Array to store your favourite quotes, such as...

```
var favouriteQuotesArray: [String] = []

func makeQuoteFavourite() {

    let currentQuote = dreamFact.dreamArray[factIndex]
    favouriteQuotesArray.append(currentQuote)
}
```

Comment: Getting mutating array only has member append error